# JavaScript, update object with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript

I have an object with this static structure:

```
let obj = {
    "id": "",
    "id_configuration": "",
    "comment": "",
    "mw_assigned": "",
};
```

I want to update it's properties by key. For example, if I receive

```
const key = 'mw_assigned'
const value = '23'
```

Then I want to update the object and to have:

```
let obj = {
    "id": "",
    "id_configuration": "",
    "comment": "",
    "mw_assigned": "23",
};
```

How could I do? I was trying to create a new object, something like this:

```
const new_obj = { ...obj, key: value }
```

I don't know how to set the name of the key and value from the vars

Comment: const new_obj = { ...obj, [key]: value }
Simple as that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

> This is reminiscent of the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) of the property accessor
>   syntax

```js
let obj = {
  "id": "",
  "id_configuration": "",
  "comment": "",
  "mw_assigned": "",
};

const key = 'mw_assigned'
const value = '23'

const new_obj = { ...obj, [key]: value }

console.log(new_obj)
```

Comment: That's not "bracket notation". What you're using is a _[computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)_

Comment: Thanks, I could't learn that concept if my question were removed by duplicated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use as `obj[key]`

```js
  let obj = {
        "id": "",
        "id_configuration": "",
        "comment": "",
        "mw_assigned": "",
    };

const key = 'mw_assigned';
const value = '23';

   // obj[key] = value;

   const new_obj = { ...obj,  [key]: value }
console.log(new_obj );
```

Comment: FYI, op wants to create a new object